# List Коллекция с уникальными элементами

Tags: java, коллекции

Есть ли в Java List с уникальными элементами. Тобишь чтобы функции были такие же как у `ArrayList`, но работало как в `HashSet`.

Чтобы не повторялись в `ArrayList` элементы

Comment: А чем вам set не угодил?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Если я правильно понял, Вам нужно, что-бы элементы были упорядочены в порядке добавления и при этом имели уникальность.

Есть **LinkedHashSet** - хранит э-ты в порядке добавления и не содержит повторений.
Он расширяет класс HashSet, не добавляя никаких новых методов.